# Having trouble injecting functions into the native window

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to inject a getStatus function into `window`. Specifically I want to stick it on windows returned by `window.open`:

```
window.open = function (open) {
    return function (url, name, opts) {
        var windowObj = open.call(window, url, name, opts);

        windowObj.getStatus = function () {
            return 1;
        };

        return windowObj;
    };
}(window.open)
```

Somewhere else in my code, I do:

```
var myWindow = window.open("...", "...", "...");
var a = myWindow.getStatus();
```

Sometimes when I debug from Visual Studio 2015, I can successfully call the function, and sometimes I can't and get a crash:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getStatus'

Has anyone experienced issues like this? Feels like a timing issue. Possibly an issue with the debugger.

Comment: So does that mean, if you are not debugging, `getStatus()` executes without any issues. And only when you are debugging you face the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried it without a debugger yet. It was just my suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone experienced issues like this?

No. I tried it multiple times with debugging in Visual Studio 2013 Express edition and it did not crash. I was able to debug it without any issue.

---

Note: with the simplified version of the question, following response may sound out of context.

---

Frankly speaking I had never tried overriding window's default behavior. But looking at your attempt it was very tempting to give it a try. :)

So I tried it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/4hhrb255/

And atleast the `alert(1)` is getting executed consistently. I've also modified it to call native `addEventListener` and it also seems to work with following conditions:

1. I've used `click` event instead of `close`. `beforeunload` also works.
2. I've use "about:blank" as the URL.

AFAIK, if you are opening a different page in your child window then you can't handle it's JS events in your parent window. You will need to handle appropriate JS events in the page that is opened in child window and from those handlers you will need to pass on the information to `window.opener`.

Regarding `close` event, I've never used it (or even heard about it :| ). Instead `unload` / `beforeunload` are the two events that are usually used.

Comment: I've simplified my question. I don't think it has to do with overriding addEventListener, but with injecting any function onto the window object.